# start scrolling after delay of x seconds (smoothdivscroll)

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I am using the jQuery Plugin Smooth Div Scroll, it works perfectly fine but i would like the scrolling to start not immediately but after a delay of two seconds.

Here is how it looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
        mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
        manualContinuousScrolling: true,
        autoScrollingMode: "onStart"
    });
});
</script>
```

Here are all the options explained: http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/options.html

Could someone maybe take a quick look? I'm stuck unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to edit the source code to accomplish what you want - everything you need is provided by the plugin in the form of callbacks and public methods. Here's the source code to a working example that does what you want:

```
// Initialization
var scroller = $("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
    autoScrollingMode: "always",
    setupComplete: function() {
        scroller.smoothDivScroll("stopAutoScrolling");
    }
});

 setTimeout(function(){
     scroller.smoothDivScroll("startAutoScrolling");
 },2000) //2000 is delay in milliseconds
```

Here is a JSFiddle where you can try it:

http://jsfiddle.net/yTTah/

Comment: Thank you for trying! I have tried to apply it to the file that I have, but it didn't work out. Here is what I'm talking about: http://martindudekphoto.com/wp-content/themes/PhotoPro/js/scroll_init.js

Comment: Hi! In the file above you don't have any autoscrolling at all so there's nothing to delay. Or am I missing something?